# How to send a signal / interrupt from kernel built in module to a loadable kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am new to linux kernel programming. I am developing a simple Loadable Kernel 
Module which needs info whenever there is a change in scheduler runqueue
(say `rq_rt` only). So I need to send a signal or interrupt to my kernel module (say a `interrupt` or `signal handler` in my module ) from the scheduler's functions (`enqueue_rt`, `dequeue_rt`, `current_premept` etc....).

Can anyone suggest a method how to send such signals or interrupts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also for an efficient solution, you can make use of function pointers from kernel source code.

But the problem here is you have to modify Linux source code. Be very careful when you do such modifications.

1. Implement a NULL function pointer from you Linux source code - Call to this function pointer from the kernel routine (check for NULL and do)
2. Export the symbol
3. Provide a local function address to this symbol from your loadable module.

That's it...!!! You will get a function call from the kernel routine. Also make sure that when you exit the module, put the symbol back to NULL, otherwise kernel will crash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Finally I got the solution. We can make use of kernel tracing mechanism, ftrace.
This doesn't require any kernel modifications, but we can hook to kernel functions which are not trace protected.

More details are available [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/ftrace-uses.html)